# is it possible to use induction to prove the following?

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

I know for sure that there is some easy way to prove what I am about to tell, but, at first, I'd like to know if I can set up a proof by induction for two "cross-referenced formulas".

I have two matrices A ($n\times n$) and B ($n\times n$).
$$A_n=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1-a & 1 &... & 1 \\
1 & 1-a&... &1 \\
... & ... & ...&...\\
1 & ... &1 & 1-a \end{array} \right) $$
$$B_n=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 &... & 1 \\
1 & 1-a&... &1 \\
... & ... & ...&...\\
1 & ... &1 & 1-a \end{array} \right) $$

$$\det A_n=(1-a)\det A_{n-1}-(n-1)\det B_{n-1}$$
$$\det B_n=\det A_{n-1}-(n-1) \det B_{n-1}$$

$$\det A_n=(-1)^n a^{n-1}(a-n)$$
$$\det B_n=(-1)^{n-1}a^{n-1}$$

The formulas I am really sure they are ok.I get no contradiction using them together, but how can I make a proof without killing the logic??

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two recurrences (for $\det A_n$ and $\det B_n$) are clearly correct, so it’s just a matter of proving the two closed forms, and you can use an ordinary induction argument to prove them simultaneously.

They are both clearly correct when $n=1$. Suppose that they hold for some $n\ge 1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\det A_{n+1}&=(1-a)\det A_n-n\deg B_n\\
&=(1-a)(-1)^na^{n-1}(a-n)-n(-1)^{n-1}a^{n-1}\\
&=(1-a)(-1)^na^n-n(1-a)(-1)^na^{n-1}-n(-1)^{n-1}a^{n-1}\\
&=(1-a)(-1)^na^n+n(-1)^na^n\\
&=(n+1-a)(-1)^na^n\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}a^n\big(a-(n+1)\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\det B_{n+1}&=\det A_n-(n-1)\det B_n\\
&=(-1)^na^{n-1}(a-n)-n(-1)^{n-1}a^{n-1}\\
&=(-1)^na^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the result follows by induction on $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of that, but something bothers me. how do I know that det An= (−1)^n a^(n−1) (a−n) is true? [and det Bn =...] because with the induction I prove the first pair of equalities, but should't I prove the second pair too, maybe before? I'm pretty confused..

Comment: @user3621272: That’s the induction hypothesis. Are you familiar with proofs by induction?

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm not so familiar with that. Why the induction hypotesis (for the first pair of equalities) hold for the second too?

Comment: @user3621272: The first pair of equations clearly hold without any need for a proof by induction: they come from the expansion by cofactors. They provide a recurrence that allows us to calculate $A_n$ and $B_n$ provided that we already know $A_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-1}$. It’s only the last two equations that have to be proved. Let $P(k)$ be the statement that both of them are true when $n=k$. We prove that $P(1)$ holds by simply checking the algebra. Then we show that **if** $P(k)$ holds for some $k\ge 1$, **then** $P(k+1)$ also holds. That’s what my calculations did. The principle of ...

Comment: ... induction then says that $P(k)$ holds for all $k\ge 1$.

Comment: Aaah, ok, now I think I can see. The first pair is correct by definition. and we prove the second pair by induction substituting to the definition; or something like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3621272: You’re very welcome.